# Is it possible to check a string comparing two regex then adding it to a dictionary?

Tags: python, regex

**Question**

How can I run through the string so that when `locationRegex` condition is met it will add it's output to a dictionary, then add any subsequent numbers from `numbersRegex` to the same dictionary then create a new one with the next location arrives. As shown in `Desired output`.

**Code**

```
import re
# Text to check
text = "Italy Roma 20 40 10 4902520 10290" \
       "Italy Milan 20 10 49 20 1030" \
       "Germany Berlin 20 10 10 10 29 490" \
       "Germany Frankfurt 20 0 0 0 0" \
       "Luxemburg Luxemburg 20 10 49"

# regex to find location
locationRegex = re.compile(r'[A-Z]\w+\s[A-Z]\w+')
# regex to find numbers
numberRegex = re.compile(r'[0-9]+')

# Desired output
locations = {'Italy Roma': {'numbers': [10, 40, 10, 4902520]},
             'Italy Milan': {'numbers': [20, 10, 49, 20, 1030]}}
```

**What I have tried**

I have ran the regex against the string with `re.findall` however I have the issue of assigning the numbers to the locations as they sit in two separate pots of locations and numbers.

Comment: Have you atually tried to extract the matches by using `re.findall`/`re.finditer`?

Comment: Yes, however, I am finding it difficult to add the number values to the location. As I currently have two separate piles of locations and numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single regex to split the text in chunks, use groups within the regex to separate the data (note the parenthesis), and finally use `split` to split the number string on the spaces:

```
import re

text = (
    "Italy Roma 20 40 10 4902520 10290"
    "Italy Milan 20 10 49 20 1030"
    "Germany Berlin 20 10 10 10 29 490"
    "Germany Frankfurt 20 0 0 0 0"
    "Luxemburg Luxemburg 20 10 49"
)

line_regex = re.compile(r"([A-Z]\w+\s[A-Z]\w+) ([0-9 ]+)")

loc_dict = {}

for match in re.finditer(line_regex, text):
    print(match.group(1))
    print(match.group(2))

    loc_dict[match.group(1)] = {"numbers": match.group(2).split(" ")}

print(loc_dict)
```

The dict will be:

```
{'Italy Roma': {'numbers': ['20', '40', '10', '4902520', '10290']},
 'Italy Milan': {'numbers': ['20', '10', '49', '20', '1030']},
 'Germany Berlin': {'numbers': ['20', '10', '10', '10', '29', '490']},
 'Germany Frankfurt': {'numbers': ['20', '0', '0', '0', '0']},
 'Luxemburg Luxemburg': {'numbers': ['20', '10', '49']}}
```

Note that you should check for edge cases: no numbers, cities with a space in the name and so on.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! I am pretty new to Regex and was thinking only in terms of loops. I appreciate you taking the time to answer in such detail.